# getting syntaxhighlighter to recognize html added by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, live, syntaxhighlighter

I'm trying to make a wysiwyg editor of sorts..  I want to be able to preview code snippets I am putting into my website before posting them.  I have gotten syntaxhighlighter to work properly..  But I want to change HTML on the page and have syntaxhighlighter effect that..

I have tried both of these methods

```
    $('#write').live('click', function() {
          myOut.innerHTML = myText.value;
          SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });

    btnWrite.onclick = function()
    {
           myOut.innerHTML = myText.value;
           SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    }
```

SyntaxHighlighter.all() sees the code snippets being added as the page loads.. But I can't seem to get it to see any user added code snippets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370738/jquery-load-issue

my question was answered here..