# jQuery load() can not work with syntaxhighlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntaxhighlighter

I use [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) in my page and it works well.

```
<pre id="code" class="brush:js">
some code here
</pre>
```

But it doesn't work when I save to a html file then use jquery load function to load them.

```
$(function(){
  $("#test").load("test.html");
});
```

Everything is displayed well except the code scope. Could some one tell me why? Thx!

Comment: What's in test.html? What is #test? Please, add more info to your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery load issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370738/jquery-load-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
```

Comment: You should write how "this" answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#test` into `#code`:

```
$(function(){
  $("#code").load("test.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to run this code to initialize the syntax highlighter after you have dynamically loaded your code:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

This could probably be done by the following:

```
$(function(){
  $("#code").load("test.html", function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });
});
```